# Python 2.7 append values to dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries with identical keys.

```
d1 = {'Dog':[7,2],'Cat':[5,2]}
d2 = {'Dog':1,'Cat':4}
```

Is there a good way of combining them so that I can have one dictionary that looks like this?

```
d = {'Dog':[7,2,1],'Cat':[5,2,4]}
```

Comment: The `duplicate` is not an answer to this question.  It should be reopened or given a correct duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```python
for key, value in d2.iteritems():
    if key in d1:
        d1[key].append(value)
```

Comment: You could just do `for key in d2:`

Answer (score 2):

If one contains lists and the other contains ints, you can do:

```
d = {key:[d2[key]] + d1[key] for key in d1}
```